# Can I add a prohibited word list to restrict publishing when encountered?

Tags: drupal, drupal-input-format

I have some drupal sites, and a couple of editors putting content constantly.
What I want to do is restrict them to their word vocabulary (restrict foul language)
so it will simple restrict them from publishing if using any of the words I'm providing...

Does such a module exists? or can this be done programaticaly?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordfilter module](https://drupal.org/project/wordfilter) should do what you're looking for.

Comment: In that case the WebPurify module provides "the option of blocking profane nodes": http://drupal.org/project/webpurify The module itself is free, but the service requires a paid subscription.